# Why do we drop the abolute value bars when doing indefinite integration?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Say, for instance, we're trying to solve $\frac{dy}{dx}=y\cos(x)$.

Separating the variables, we get: $$\int \frac{1}{y}dy=\int \cos(x) dx.$$

So $\ln|y|=\sin(x)+c \iff |y|=Ae^{\sin(x)}$ (where $A:=e^c$), yielding:

$$y=\pm Ae^{\sin(x)}$$, which is inconsistent with Wolfram Alpha's $y=Ae^{\sin(x)}$.

Now, I know that $A$ could be either positive or negative, but it's a constant, so it's **either** one **or** the other.

So, what I'm asking is: how can WA justify dropping the absolute value bars?

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking about whether it's valid to drop the absolute value bars in general, or are you asking why Wolfram Alpha does in this case?

Comment: Not specific to WA; it was just a source. Why, in general , can we do that?

Comment: @alexqwx We can't. Wolfram Alpha doesn't even include the absolute value when integrating $x\mapsto \frac 1 x$. It is wrong.

Comment: So is my solution (with the $\pm$) right, then?

Comment: @alexqwx In this case both you and wolfram alpha are correct.

Comment: @GitGud But, it's either one or the other. Which is it?

Comment: @alexqwx: Both.  You've chosen $$A_1 = e^C$$ and they have chosen $$A_2 = \pm e^C$$.  Either one is valid.

Comment: @GitGud: What is wrong? Listing $\int\frac 1x\,\mathrm{d}x = \ln(x)$ is perfectly correct, just like $\int\frac 1x\,\mathrm{d}x = \ln(|x|)$ is – just take the derivative to check. The difference between the two is a piecewise constant – for real $x$. The form without the absolute values is even valid for complex $x$.

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig It is wrong because the point is to find all antiderivatives and not just some.

Comment: @GitGud $\ln(x)$ is an antiderivative, just like $\ln(x)+H(x)$ (with $H$ the Heaviside step function) or $\ln(|x|)$ or an uncountably infinite number of other expressions are. Sure, you can ask that all of these include a “+ C” term, which I regard as pointless boilerplate. But there’s no reason to regard $\ln(|x|)$ as inherently better. Sure, it’s one of the real-valued antiderivatives. So what, big deal. It’s also one that makes differential-algebraic manipulations harder than they need be. Last discussion tidbit on here from me, I promise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have
$$
|y| = A\sin x = e^Ce^{\sin x}.
$$
The number $e^C$ is necessarily positive if $C$ is real.  Hence
$$
|y|= (\text{a positive constant}\cdot e^{\sin x}).
$$

From this it follows that
$$
y = (\text{a non-zero constant}\cdot e^{\sin x}).
$$

Then the question is why the value $0$ is allowed.  You'll notice that you divided by $y$ fairly early and you can't divide by $0$.  This method finds only non-zero solutions.  Whether the function in which the constant is $0$ is a solution can be checked separately by plugging it into the original equation.

Comment: Shouldn't $\sin(x)$ be in the exponent?

So, the reason that we can drop that absolute value bars is that $A$ is just any (non-zero) real number? And what about in definite integration? Obviously, we have to get a unique result, so do we choose plus or minus (whatever the constant happens to be)?

Comment: @alexqwx : Sorry --- my attention was on the "constant".  Fixed. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @alexqwx: "*Obviously, we have to get a unique result*" - I think this may be part of your confusion. We don't get a unique result. We get a whole huge set of functions that fit the constraints.

Comment: @user2357112 I understand now the part about indefinite integration. But what about doing definite integration? Do we choose plus or minus (whatever $A$ turns out to be)?

Comment: @alexqwx: Solving a differential equation isn't integration, definite or otherwise. When finding a particular solution (as opposed to finding the general solution, which we're doing here), whether we put a positive or negative sign there, we'll get the same function. If we put a positive sign there and get $A=5$, then we would have gotten $A=-5$ with a minus sign, resulting in the same function.

Comment: @alexqwx: By the way, if you're going to accept an answer, this one is better than mine. It caught several things I didn't, particularly the fact that initially, with $A=e^c$, $A$ has to be positive.

Comment: @user2357112 : Solving the differential equation $y'=\cos x$ is definitely indefinite integration.  And it's not unusual to hear it said that one is "integrating" a differential equation when one is finding its solution.

Comment: No, putting `sin` in the exponent is not "fixed".  You still are making $$|y| = A \sin x$$, but it is not

Comment: @MichaelHardy I am confused as to how, on your third step, you got a non-zero constant. Whether or not it is negative depends on the value of $y$ so that it satisfies the second step. It depends on $y$, so it is not a constant.

Comment: If the absolute value of $y$ is a positive constant times some function then either $y$ is a nonzero constant times that function or else it's a constant times something whose values remain in the set $\{\pm1\}$.  But this one will have no changes in sign. Notice that the exponential function be which you're multiplying is always positive. Any change in sign would involve a discontinuity since the exponential function does not approach $0$ at any finite point in the domain.

Answer (score 9):

$-Ae^{\sin x}$ is just $Ae^{\sin x}$ with a different $A$.

Comment: Yes, but $A$ is constant, so is either positive or negative.

Comment: @alexqwx: The solution set is the set of functions of the form $f(x) = Ae^{\sin x}$, where each function is allowed to have a different value of $A$. Functions of the form $f(x) = -Ae^{\sin x}$ are already included; for example, the function $f(x) = -Ae^{\sin x}$ with $A=5$ is already in there as $f(x) = Ae^{\sin x}$ with $A=-5$.

Comment: @alexqwx Would you say that $A$ is a constant so it is either even, odd, or not an integer (and thus, we need at least six cases)?

Comment: @GammaFunction I take your point. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote is not a good proof (divide by $y$: does it mean $y\neq 0$? what about the solution $y(x)=0$?).

A better one:

**Theorem:**
   the general solution of the equation $y'(x) = a'(x)y(x)$ on the interval $[a,b]$ is:
   $$y(x) = C\exp a(x), C\in\Bbb R$$

**Proof:** consider $x\to y(x) \exp(-a(x))$ and prove this is a constant.